# Can I use an Xbox 360 controller to play Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, xbox-one

So I broke my Xbox One controller, and while it is easy enough to go out and buy another, I have a couple of Xbox 360 controllers.

Is there any way to use an Xbox 360 controller to play Xbox One?

Comment: Rockband 4 comes with an adapter to use the old "instruments" which are basically just 360 controllers with different layout. Maybe it works with the normal 360 controllers in other games. I will try it out some time this week. Probably not the solution your are looking for but worth finding out ;-)

Comment: Tried this and it didn't work.  The Rock Band 4 legacy adapter only works with instrument controllers, not gamepads :(

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The Xbox One cannot directly accept input from an Xbox 360 controller - however, with Windows 10, there is a work around.

Windows 10 allows you to set up your Xbox One to stream to your computer. While streaming to your computer, you are directed to connect the controller into the computer, not the Xbox One.

In this form, Xbox 360 controllers will work for playing Xbox One games. You can directly plug in a wired controller, [or use an adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HZFCT2), if you are using the wireless controllers.

Comment: Figured it was worth putting this up in case other users have the same question. Even Microsoft and EB informed me it wouldn't work, but what luck, I am currently playing Destiny this way as I post.

Comment: I hate that the XBO doesn't support 360 controllers, but I love the workaround. I wonder if Microsoft will detect and block this at some stage...

Comment: I would love some feedback on whether other controllers work. I believe this was actually Microsoft having to cover for a different feature they promised would be released with streaming. Originally they advertised that we would use a keyboard and mouse.

Answer (score -2):

You can only use the Xbox 360 controller for the Xbox One by having an Xbox 360 controller with a cord to connect it to.

Comment: Yeah no. This was not hard to test, and the first thing I tried. 360 controller outright does not recognise directly on a One console.

Comment: I don't know why they have downvoted this...